# when a javascript object property which is an array is accessed directly, it shows as empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I have the strangest problem and I can't for the life of me figure it out.
If I do this:

```
console.log(settings);
```

I get this:

```
Object{
activeImage: 0
containerBorderSize: 10
containerResizeSpeed: 400
fixedNavigation: false
imageArray: Array[58]
imageBlank: "http://www.cappellaniauniromatre.org/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/jquery.lightbox/lightbox-blank.gif"
imageBtnClose: "http://www.cappellaniauniromatre.org/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/jquery.lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif"
imageBtnNext: "http://www.cappellaniauniromatre.org/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/jquery.lightbox/lightbox-btn-next.gif"
imageBtnPrev: "http://www.cappellaniauniromatre.org/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/jquery.lightbox/lightbox-btn-prev.gif"
imageLoading: "http://www.cappellaniauniromatre.org/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/jquery.lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif"
keyToClose: "c"
keyToNext: "n"
keyToPrev: "p"
overlayBgColor: "#000"
overlayOpacity: 0.8
txtImage: "Image"
txtOf: "of"
__proto__: Object
}
```

Now if I do this instead:

```
console.log(settings.imageArray);
```

I get an empty array!

```
[]
```

I know this array has 58 elements, why does it show as empty if I access the property directly?
If I try to access any other property directly, I get the correct value. But if I try to access "imageArray", I get an empty array. Why ever could that be?

Comment: Hard to tell, is there any way you could make a live demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: that's strange. have you try it in more then one browser? chrome and firefox+firebug for example?

Comment: @elclanrs: http://jsfiddle.net/K4BEs/

Comment: Here is the page it is happening on: http://www.cappellaniauniromatre.org/galleria/nggallery/2013-2014/salsicciata/
When you click on the first image the console.logs are called, as the lightbox is opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log(settings)` puts a live reference to `settings` into the console. That means that any changes to `settings` after `console.log(settings)` will show up in the console.

For example:

```
var settings = { imageArray: [ ] };
console.log(settings);
console.log(settings.imageArray);
settings.imageArray = [ 'where', 'is', 'pancakes', 'house?' ];
console.log(settings.imageArray);
```

will give you this in the console:

```
Object
    imageArray: Array[4]
[]
["where", "is", "pancakes", "house?"]
```

The first `console.log(settings.imageArray)` is empty and stays empty because the `settings.imageArray` reference is replaced.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K4BEs/

Comment: I am not making consecutive calls, I am substituting the same call... Though I think I might understand, you mean that the array is being emptied afterwards so it shows up as empty if I call it directly but not if I call the object it is stored in?

Comment: How does the first console.log(settings) output Array[4] if you haven't set the length of the array yet?

Comment: @NickM: Because we assign `["where", "is", "pancakes", "house?"]` to `settings.imageArray` later and `console.log(settings)` does not put a snapshot of `settings` into the console, it puts the real live object in there.

Comment: @Lwangaman: The array is empty when you `console.log(settings.imageArray)`, then the array changes, then you look at what's in `settings`.

Comment: ok I see, so the values in the console are updated basically as the object is populated

Comment: Looking better at the structure of the code I see that this is what is happening in fact, thanks choosing this as the answer.

Comment: If you need the console to log an object as it is when you `console.log` then you have to clone it (using whatever `_.clone`, `_.extend`, `$.extend`, ... tools you have at hand), `JSON.stringify()` it, or something similar. This behavior is a bit confusing the first time you see it (and that usually involves an AJAX call but not always).

Comment: Thought it would be of interest that in Chrome console, when you expand a logged object to view the nested properties etc you get an little "i" which when you hover over states "Object state below is captured on first expansion"

Comment: @pero: Interesting, any idea when that started happening? I just noticed the "i" after you pointed it out. That would explain some of the confusing behavior I've seen with short arrays (i.e. arrays short enough to be expanded by default).